# how to fix CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Campground"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

CastError keeps returning when navigating to /campgrounds/new
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Campground"

```
const Campground = require('./models/campgrounds');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Yelpie');


const app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('./campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
    const campgrounds = await Campground.find({});
    res.render('./campgrounds/index', { campgrounds });
});

app.get('./campgrounds/new',  (req, res) => {
    res.render('./campgrounds/new');
});

app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async(req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('./campgrounds/show', { campground });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Can you post the value of the `id` parameter that you are passing to the route?